# I need to highlight the check text in color

Tags: django

When I start to check the words, I have what has come in green, and the error is red, and when I have an error, it does not highlight it in red, but only displays my error message. How can I make it highlight the error?

```
view.py
```

```
@login_required
@permission_required("service.add_post")
def create_post(req):
form = PostForm()
if req.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(req.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        title = form.cleaned_data.get("title")
        if title != "POST":
            messages.error(req, f"Something went wrong")
            return redirect('index')
        # id = form.cleaned_data.get("pk")
        messages.success(req, f"Post {title} was created successfully")
        return redirect('index')
return render(req, "create_post.html", {"form":form})
```

```
create_post.html
```

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Create Post</h1>
   <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <button class="btn btn-primary">Create New Post</button>
```

```

Already changed a lot of things but nothing helped.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this in your template:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
             <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} msg">
            {{ message }}
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nothing succeeded